# Wireless router disconnects when one computer on the network hibernates

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, hibernate

We have a fairly standard wireless setup using a Trendnet TEW-639GR. Connected to it wirelessly, most of the time, are two Windows computers, a Mac, and a couple of mobile devices.

We've noticed an odd pattern where the wireless signal seems to drop out for a while immediately following one of the Windows computers being hibernated. There doesn't seem to be anything special about that computer and the router, they're not physically connected in any way.

Any suggestions on where to begin looking for the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running any Trendnet supplied configuration software on that computer? I don't know Trendnet's products, but most routers these days tend to come with a CD that lets you configure it - it's not a big stretch to think that the CD might have installed a manager on your computer, and that said manager is more active than you might have realized.

If this is the case, perhaps the router is busy trying to re-attach to the manager. Once it gives up, it goes back to normal operation.

Comment: I try to avoid installing stuff like that, and after double-checking, I can't find any Trendnet software on the computer. This is all just using Windows' wireless connection manager.

Comment: @tghw - oh well, it was worth a shot. I also avoid such things, but some folks find them handy.